# Is it possible to have the Windows Azure emulator open the browser to a URL other than 127.0.0.1

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-web-roles

Simple question but lots of meaning/discussion behind!!!

Is it possible to have the Windows Azure emulator open the browser to a URL other than 127.0.0.1 and port 81?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the steps to change 127.0.0.1 to desire IP

**Compute Emulator Settings:**

1. Go to %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric
2. Take backup of “DevFC.exe.config” so that if something goes you can
   revert it back.
3. Change following settings to desired IP address range and subnet:

   - <add key="StartIPAddress" value="192.168.0.20"/> (This can be IP address on your machine)
   - <add key="EndIPAddress" value=”192.168.0.40" />
   - <add key="VipPoolStartIPAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
   - <add key="VipPoolEndIPAddress" value="127.0.0.255" />
   - <add key="DefaultGateway" value="192.168.0.1" />
   - <add key="SubnetMask" value="255.255.255.0" />
4. Save the config file.
5. Restart the compute emulator.

**Storage Emulator Settings:**

6. Go to %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devstore
7. Take backup of “DSServiceLDB.exe.config” so that if something goes you can revert it back.
8. Take backup of “DSServiceSQL.exe.config” so that if something goes you can revert it back.
9. Change the IP address 127.0.0.1 to desired IP address in the services section of both the config file:

   - <services>
   - <service name="Blob" url="http: //192.168.1.20:10000/"/>
   - <service name="Queue" url="http: //192.168.1.20:10001/"/>
   - <service name="Table" url="http: //192.168.1.20:10002/"/>
   - </services>
10. Save both the config files and restart the storage emulator.

Finally change the storage account connection string in visual studio so that it points to proper IP address. The emulator uses following credentials:

**Account Name:** devstoreaccount1

**Account key:**
Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==

**Note:** *If the above account key does not work then check account key in “DSServiceSQL.exe.config” file under “<accounts>” section.*

Make sure you specify custom endpoint based on your IP address as shown in the screen shots below.

[image]

[image]

That’s all needed to run Azure Emulator on local network!

Original blog: http://blog.piyushthacker.com/?p=24

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Right click the project -> Properties -> Web -> Open Specific Page **OR** Start Url