# Change running IP of Azure Storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm using the "new" Azure storage emulator command-line edition. In the previous version it was possible to change IP like 127.0.0.1 -> 192.168.41.123 when [running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337246/is-it-possible-to-have-the-windows-azure-emulator-open-the-browser-to-a-url-othe) .

I can not locate the same file anymore and have looked into the other config files, but so far with no luck. Anyone knows how to change it?

Comment: By `config file` - are you referring to the `system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in Windows?

Comment: no the config of azure storage emulator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the IP address in `AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator` directory.

For example, below I have changed the port from `10000` to `20000`.

```xml
<services>
  <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:20000/"/>
  <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:20001/"/>
  <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:20002/"/>
</services>
```

You would need to restart the storage emulator for this change to take effect.

Also, please note that you can't use standard `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` connection string. You must specify custom endpoints in your connection string:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:20000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:20002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:20001/devstoreaccount1;/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Hmm tried both, but no luck so far. Can you browse the storage from within visual studio afterwords? Note I changed the IP, not the port

Comment: Have you tried using this in the code? I don't think this would work in Visual Studio because my guess is Visual Studio Server explorer tries to connect via standard connection string (`UseDevelopmentStorage=true`) which tries to  connect to standard storage emulator endpoints.

Comment: I think you're right. First I started storage Emulator from a command window and running the status command I got the expected ip/port. But when I started my vs project, I kept getting a popup that the emulator was started when ever I debugged the project. Current solution is to use an Azure hosted blob storage...

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but you can try adding development storage account as cloud storage account using Visual Studio UI to add a cloud storage account but you specify custom endpoints as mentioned in my answer above. Give it a try and see if that works.

Comment: I just tried connecting to custom endpoints in Visual Studio and it looks like it is not possible. So please discard my previous comment.

Comment: Great post but not being able to use UseDevelopmentStorage=true to point to a different port sucks. In a team environment - I have a local issue and need to run storage emulator on different ports to other team members we can't share the same configuration files. It would be better if we could change the ports UseDevelopmentStorage=true generates locally on each dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config
```

Worked, then stop and start the emulator. Check if that is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use port forwarding because of the instability of Azure Emulator. However, it doesn't work when `connectaddress` is 127.0.0.1 using the built-in tool `netsh` on my windows 7 (see for detail: [problem with adding a portproxy using netsh](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e794910b-9325-4ef9-be82-3e57925e6586/problem-with-adding-a-portproxy-using-netsh?forum=winservergen&prof=required#6e55ec40-75a1-4707-aba5-1eabe917fbfc)). I research and use [PassPort port forwarding utility Win XP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/) to help me with port forwarding.

[image]