# Debug Azure functions in Visual Studio without starting the emulator

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage

I have an Azure functions project that I normally run through calling `func.exe`. The docker-compose has azurite.

Sometimes I need to step through debug in visual studio so I `Ctrl+C` the cli runtime and hit `F5` in visual studio. However, then I have to `docker-compose stop azurite` because Visual Studio wants to start  up storage emulator before it starts up func.exe. Is there any way I can make Visual Studio not start up the function emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <StartDevelopmentStorage>false</StartDevelopmentStorage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As recommended by Microsoft [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-functions-not-starting-in-vs-with-azurite-if/1155814)

Answer (score 0):

I think you got misunderstanding of using **Azurite** with Visual Studio.

1. Why use **storage emulator**?

> Because an Azure Function requires a storage account, one is assigned or created when you publish your project to Azure. An HTTP
> trigger doesn't use an Azure Storage account connection string; all
> other trigger types **require a valid Azure Storage account connection
> string.**

2. How to use **Azurite**? Refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/use-azurite-to-run-automated-tests#run-tests-on-your-local-machine).

> (1) Install the latest version of Python
>
> (2) Install Azure Storage Explorer
>
> (3) Install and run Azurite:

```
# Install Azurite
npm install -g azurite

# Create an Azurite directory
mkdir c:/azurite

# Launch Azurite locally
azurite --silent --location c:\azurite --debug c:\azurite\debug.log
```

Then use it just like how you use Azure Storage Account, modify the connection string. Get the ConnectionString from Storage Explorer.

## Notice:

Run your Function from VS.
If you got the issue below, please [modify the IP of your storage emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37120309/13586071)

[image]

Then you could run it successfully:

[image]